# Python: Building a Client for a Large Private undocumented API, How to best structure, document, and cache?

Tags: python, json, api

I'm trying to build a client / interface for a large private and undocumented API, it exclusively takes and returns pretty verbose JSON, it also has a "HyperMedia" definition section returned on some calls that are website page related, which have been helpful for me to better fit my functions to the API,

However the scale is growing beyond anything I've had to deal with before, all up it has around 800 endpoints, many of them return large chunks of the same data as others,

So far I've been manually creating functions for each of them with the requests library, and just working with the JSON as a dictionary, but its getting to the point that I feel I need a better architecture, some way to say parameters X Y and Z from this group of returns is all the exact same data,

My hope is to map this into a cache or some intermediate structure, e.g. a database, to prevent how much I need to pull from the rather slow API, and say reduce manually juggling all those endpoints for any consumers that will be using the interface.

Would you have any suggestions on names or methods I might search for? I am left feeling something similar to this should be a solved problem, likely involving a schema of some type, but there seems to be a gap between what I'm finding which seems to lean more towards hosting an API and I've struggled to see how it might be adapted?

Below is an example of one of the Hypermedia sections I talked about, Parts of the API I've worked out from the chunks included in some returns, however I've not found much information about this schema type, and it does leave a lot of gaps such as return type information, but it does give a good concept for how verbose a lot of the JSON is,

```
"DateLoaded": "2023-03-03T23:18:35+00:00",
"RemoveAssetTemplate": {
    "HyperMedia": {
        "Links": [
            {
                "ModifyData": false,
                "ExcludeBodyFromResponse": false,
                "Rel": "removeAsset",
                "Uri": "API/fleet-admin/assets/organisations/:orgID/:assetId",
                "Verb": "DELETE",
                "Params": {
                    "assetId": "@assetId",
                    "orgId": "@orgId",
                },
                "Host": null,
                "SuppressAuthentication": false
            }
        ]
    }
},
"CommissioningRequestTemplate": {
    "HyperMedia": {
        "Links": [
            {
                "ModifyData": false,
                "ExcludeBodyFromResponse": false,
                "Rel": "resendCommissioningRequest",
                "Uri": "API/fleet-admin/assets/commissioning/:orgId/:assetId/request",
                "Verb": "GET",
                "Params": {
                    "assetId": "@assetId"
                    "orgId": "@orgId",
                },
                "Host": null,
                "SuppressAuthentication": false
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

Comment: This seems more like a [softwareengineering.se] question.

Comment: Thank you for that, is there any easy way to transfer this question there, or would it be better to delete and recreate over there?

Comment: You can flag the question and ask the moderators to migrate it.